# Basic 2, 8, or 16 color, wired display

Tags: display, terminal

Wondering what the most basic display is that you can get that works with the machine. I see stuff like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K9THPOQ) but everything seems to be full color. Wondering if that's just how it is or if there are any displays which are so limited as to truly mimic an old terminal.

Basically I am wondering what the simplest display is that you can get that has as few colors as possible, is cable-connected with USB, and *is not a touch screen*. I have seen some monochrome OLED displays but they all seem rather small. Wondering how to get them to be 15 inches or so, or the range of sizes.

Comment: Buy a regular screen, then set your graphics in `xorg.conf` to black&white and rip the touchscreen off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a huge variety of displays you can use. I haven't seen one that connects by USB, but I'm sure that's possible too.

- Here's a [character LCD display](https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview) if that fits what you're after.
- You could also get a 3.5mm to RCA cable and use the composite video out to an old tv if you want
- There are a [wide variety of other displays](https://www.adafruit.com/category/63) out there.
- I'm sure you could even connect an old terminal if you wanted.